# AArch64 SVE/2 - Left pack elements from list

Tags: c++, arm, arm64, stream-compaction, sve

I'm trying to implement a SIMD algorithm with AArch64 [SVE](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/sve/sve-programmers-guide/introduction-to-sve/single-page) (or [SVE2](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/server-and-hpc/compile/arm-instruction-emulator/resources/tutorials/sve/sve-vs-sve2/single-page)) that takes a list of elements and only selects the ones that meet a certain condition.  It's often called Left Packing ([SSE/AVX/AVX-512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask)), or Stream Compaction ([CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059753/cuda-stream-compaction-algorithm))?

Is it possible to vectorize this operation with SVE?

Equivalent SQL and scalar code could look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Book
WHERE Price < 42
```

```cpp
int LeftPack_Scalar(int* input, int* output, int N, int limit)
{
    int outPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
       if (input[i] < limit)
          out[outPos++] = input[i];
    }
    return outPos;
}
```

One could vectorize this in SIMD with AVX-512

```cpp
int LeftPack_AVX512(int* input, int* output, int N, int limit)
{
    int outPos = 0;
    __m512i vlimit = mm512_load(limit);
    for (int i=0; i < N; i+=16) {
       __m512i vinput = mm512_load(input+i); 
       __mmask16 mask = mm512_cmp(vinput, vlimit); 
       mm512_mask_compressstore(output+outPos, mask, vinput);
       int count = mm512_popcnt(mask);
       outPos += count;
    }
    return outPos;
}
```

How can I implement it with AArch64 SVE? Is there a function similar to AVX-512 *[compress_store](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi32&expand=1241,1229)* to compress sparse data?

```cpp
int LeftPack_SVE(int* input, int* output, int N, int limit)
{
  // ...
}
```

Note: SVE has both *gather* and *scatter*, see the [short introduction to the SVE](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101726/0300/Learn-about-the-Scalable-Vector-Extension--SVE-/What-is-the-Scalable-Vector-Extension-) for further details. But I couldn't find an equivalent SVE / 2 instruction to keep the relative order of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `svcompact` to compact the active elements, then a normal linear store to store the result.